# Creating Composer Package

Tags: php, symfony, oop, interface, composer-php

I'm trying to create a composer package & i understand the basic workflow like of creating composer.json, auto loading and creating classes under `src` directory.

There is one small programming misunderstanding i have is that almost all the other packages i'm reading has interfaces and a class implementing them. I don't understand need of interfaces in this context and why we need them. I have never used interface or i'm not sure if i understand its general use case. It would be nice if someone can help me understand it.

Beside the other question i had in context to composer is how do i test / run a composer project whilst i create it?

Beside this projects that i'm referring has a `command` directory inside `src` i don't understand significance of this or its use case too. I guess it has something to do with symfony php console command.

Also there is a `bin` directory at source, now how is that useful.

Sorry if i'm being naive here but i'm just trying to understand which components fall where and why is it like that. I couldn't find a composer tutorial online past creating `composer.json`

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a lot of questions at once, but I'll try to at least address interfaces, since I believe that's the most important one.

**Interfaces** are mostly used with [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). They define methods without actually caring how the methods are actually implemented. A class may depend on an interface instead of an actual (concrete) class, which allows an easy way to swap components. Below is an example of how one might use interfaces.

```
interface PostsInterface {
    public function getPosts();
}

class JsonPostFetcher implements PostsInterface {
    public function getPosts() {
        // Load posts from JSON files here
    }
}

class MySqlPostFetcher implement PostsInterface {
    public function getPosts {
        // Load posts from a MySQL database
    }
}

class Blog {
    public function __construct(PostsInterface $fetcher) {
        // Load posts from either JSON or a database
        // depending on which fetcher is provided
        $posts = $fetcher->getPosts();
    }
}
```

Using this method anyone can now write their own code to provide posts from an external API `ApiPostFetcher`, SQLite Database `SqlitePostFetcher`, Serialized PHP files `SerializedPostFetcher` etc. One could even write a `DymmyPostFetcher` that simply returns a pretermined array of posts that could be used for testing purposes. You can then use any implementation of `PostsInterface` in your blog like in the following example.

```
$fetcher = new JsonPostFetcher(); // You can provide different fetchers here.
$blog = new Blog($fetcher);
```

If you're unfamiliar with dependency injection, I highly recommend learning it, since it will be especially useful in writing modular code.

Comment: So if i do `$blog = new Blog();` how does Blog class would know which method to call from? Since $fetcher comes from interface and it doesn't have any implementation.

Comment: You can't call `new Blog();`. It would just throw an error because it expects the fetcher parameter to be an instace of `PostInterface`. You would need to call either `new Blog(new JsonPostFetcher());` or `new Blog(new MySqlPostFetcher());`. I edited my post to show an example.

Comment: Now it make sense. Thanks.